# Is there an Iter::find() equivalent that accepts a predicate that may fail?

Tags: rust, iterator, fluent

Consider this function:

```rust
pub async fn has_table(&mut self, name: &str) -> Result<bool, sqlx::Error> {
    for r in self
        .metadata
        .get_tables(&mut self.connection, name, &Vec::new(), None, None)
        .await?
    {
        if r.try_get::<'_, &'_ str, &'_ str>("name")? == name {
            return Ok(true);
        }
    }
    Ok(false)
}
```

I would like to rewrite its body in fluent style, but I don't know how to handle the fact that `r.try_get()` may fail. Ideally I would like to be able to write something like:

```rust
Ok(
    match self
        .metadata
        .get_tables(&mut self.connection, name, &Vec::new(), None, None)
        .await?
        .iter()
        .find(|r| r.try_get::<'_, &'_ str, &'_ str>("name")? == name)
    {
        Some(_) => true,
        None => false,
    },
)
```

which is obviously invalid because the argument to `Iter::find()` must return `bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[try_find](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_find) exists but it currently is unstable.

Since you already have an implementation based on a for loop I don't think there's a more concise way to achieve this until try_find is stable.